# What does lint_package_filename_format mean?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development

In a review of a `.click` package of my app, a message contained the following:

```
lint_package_filename_format
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning message only. It is recommended that the filename for a `.click` or `.snap` package follows the format *packagename*_*version*_*architecture*.*extension*, where:

- *packagename* is the fully-qualified package name with developer namespace, e.g. `foopackage.johndoe`.
- *version* is the package version, e.g. `0.1`.
- *architecture* is the target architecture of any compiled binaries in the package, e.g. `armhf` or `amd64`.  If the package contains no compiled code, `all` should be used.  If the package is a "fat" package, containing binaries for multiple architectures, `multi` should be used.
- *extension* is either `click` or `snap`.