# What does lint_package_filename_arch_valid mean?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development

In a review of my `.click` package, a warning contained the message:

```
lint_package_filename_arch_valid
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons why you might see this message, each related to the package filename.  Firstly, ensure your package filename follows the rules outlined at:

[What does lint_package_filename_format mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/685049/what-does-lint-package-filename-format-mean)

Secondly, ensure that the *architecture* segment of the package filename is a valid architecture. Valid architectures are:

- `amd64`
- `armhf`
- `i386`
- `all`
- `multi`

Additionally, the architecture `unknown` may be used, in which case this test will be skipped.